# Installing dynamic libraries off ldd command

Tags: apt

Why are dynamic libraries gotten from
 ldd command re not installable by apt I took the name of library like this libc.so.6 example I know it's glibc but just example I mean I've taken it without the rest of text like => or leading spaces

I installed other library which is not glibc just I gave glibc as ex

Answer (score 2):

*Files*, in general, are not what one "installs", *packages* are.

To find out which *package* provides a file, use `dpkg -S`:

```
dpkg -S libc6.so.6
```